# Node JS accepting null bytes

Tags: node.js, tcp, tcpserver

Hello I am writing a simple TCP/IP project for my UNI assignment and I just bumped into a problem with reading data from sockets like this:

```
socket.on('data', function(data)
{


    g_socket +=  data.toString('utf8');
    ...
```

What happens if client sends me something like:

> ABCDEFGH\x00\x00\x02\x24

I guess my g_socket happen to get string of `ABCDEFGH$` ,getting from `console.log(g_socket)`. I believe this is because of null string near sequence `\x00\x00`. My question is how to avoid this behaviour and how to be able to access data after sequence of `ABCDEFGH`

Thanks.